# How to validate a Patch/Put request in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do I validate a Patch/Put request in Laravel

According to Laravel documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers, `put/patch` requests are handled by `update` action of a resource controller

```
Verb         Path           Action  Route Name
PUT/PATCH   /photo/{photo}  update  photo.update
```

Since a `patch` request should update partial resource and `put` request updates whole resource, how then should my `FormRequest` validation `rules` look like:

Should I be doing something like this:

```
public function rules()
{

    $rules = [];

    if($this->has('name')) $rules['name'] = 'required';
    if($this->has('email')) $rules['email'] = 'required|email';

    return $rules;
}
```

Counting on your professional answers.

Comment: Why not use the `sometimes` method from the validator. It was [specifically made for these sort of things](http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#conditionally-adding-rules).

Comment: Thank you @Andrew I know about `sometimes` but you cannot use `sometimes` in `FormRequest` which I prefer using

Comment: @Digitlimit  Just override default `getValidatorInstance` like you want in your `FormRequest` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override default `getValidatorInstance` method of your `FormRequest` class

I don't try it, but I think it should work :)
Hope the main idea is clear

```
 protected function getValidatorInstance()
    { 
        $validator =  \Validator::make($this->all(), $this->rules(),  $this->messages(), $this->attributes());
        $validator->sometimes('reason', 'required|max:500', function($input) {
           return $input->games >= 100;
        });

        return $validator;
    }
```